# HTML card icons are not fixed at that given position; they are changing with the name of the card

Tags: html, css, mobile-website, cardview

I am not good in designing part like HTML and CSS but I made a card using html and CSS and I am using PHP for fetching data form the database, I had fixed every thing in my HTML and CSS code, but the problem is that when the data is fetched from the database the top icons are moved.

I don't understand why this is happening, since there are 20-25 cards being fetched from the database the icons adjust themselves according to the names on the card.

I had used margin and padding but they both doesn't work in my CSS code.

```html
<p style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; text-transform: uppercase; position:absolute:top:0px;">
  New Star Tent House

  <!--icons-->

  <img src="icons/fav.png" style="position:relative; top:-4px; left:110px; width:20px; height:20px; -webkit-transition:all 2s .2s; -moz-transition:all 2s .3s; transition:all 2s .3s" /></a>

  <img src="icons/location.png" style="position:relative; top:-4px; left:110px; width:25px; height:25px;" />
```

I want the icons to be fixed at every card, no matter whether the name is long or short.

This image is showing the icons position where I want

[image: what I want]

This image is showing the change in icons position with respect to name

[image: what's happening]

Comment: I made you a snippet. Plesae update with images from placeholder.com and  relevant HTML

Comment: Why not float the icons right?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Remove the `left:` from `image` tag. Add a `span` or `div` to contain both of the images, and add `float:right` to the `span` so that will always stay on right.

```html
<p style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; text-transform: uppercase; position:absolute:top:0px;">
  New Star Tent House

  <!--icons-->

  <span style="float:right; display:inline-block"><img src="icons/fav.png" style="position:relative; top:-4px; width:20px; height:20px; margin-right:10px; -webkit-transition:all 2s .2s; -moz-transition:all 2s .3s; transition:all 2s .3s" /></a>

  <img src="icons/location.png" style="position:relative; top:-4px; width:25px; height:25px;" /></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try This code

```css
.icons a {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
span {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.icons {
 float: right;
}
.main-div {
 background: #075E54;
 padding: 8px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; text-transform: uppercase; position:relative;overflow:hidden;">
  <span>New Star Tent House</span>

  <!--icons-->
<div class="icons">
  <a href="#"><img src="icons/fav.png" style=" width:20px; height:20px; -webkit-transition:all 2s .2s; -moz-transition:all 2s .3s; transition:all 2s .3s" />
  </a>
<a href="#">
  <img src="icons/location.png" style="width:25px; height:25px;" />
  </a>
  </div>
  
 </div>
```